# Split Text in Python

Tags: python, text, split

Is there an easy way to split text into separate lines each time a specific type of font arises. For example, I have text that looks like this:

```
BILLY: The sky is blue. SALLY: It really is blue. SAM: I think it looks like this: terrible.
```

I'd like to split the text into lines for each speaker:

```
BILLY: The sky is blue.
SALLY: It really is blue.
SAM: I think it looks like this: terrible.
```

The speaker is always capitalized with a colon following the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import re
a="BILLY: The sky is blue. SALLY: It really is blue. SAM: I think it looks like this: terrible."
print re.split(r"\s(?=[A-Z]+:)",a)
```

You can use `re.split` for this.

Output:`['BILLY: The sky is blue.', 'SALLY: It really is blue.', 'SAM: I think it looks like this: terrible.']`

Comment: Thank you!  I'm new to this, so this is extremely helpful.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to change the text rather than have a list, you could do the following:

```
import re

text = "BILLY: The sky is blue. SALLY: It really is blue. SAM: I think it looks like this: terrible."
print re.sub(r'([A-Z]+\:)', r'\n\1', text).lstrip()
```

This would print:

```
BILLY: The sky is blue. 
SALLY: It really is blue. 
SAM: I think it looks like this: terrible.
```